# Error in building wildfly 8 in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, wildfly-8, docker-build

I am not able to run wildfly from docker file. While building dockerfile it is throwing error "/bin/bash curl: not found".Please suggest anything I am missing in dockerfile

**Dockerfile :**

```
    FROM alpine:3.2

    ENV WILDFLY_VERSION 8.2.0.Final
    ENV JBOSS_HOME /opt/jboss/wildfly
    ENV JAVA_VERSION_MAJOR 6
    ENV JAVA_VERSION_MINOR 65
    ENV JAVA_VERSION_BUILD 17
    ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk
    ENV PATH ${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
    ENV POSTGRESQL_VERSION 9.3-1101.jdbc4


    # Install Wildfly and add an admin user (password admin)
    RUN cd /tmp && \
      curl -O https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/$WILDFLY_VERSION/wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz && \
      tar xf wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz && \
      mkdir -p $JBOSS_HOME && \
      mv /tmp/wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION/* $JBOSS_HOME/ && \
      rm -r wildfly-* && \
      $JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh admin -p admin -s    
    EXPOSE 80 9990
```

interfaces
        CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0", "-Djboss.http.port=80"]

**ERROR occured**

```
docker build -f wildfly_dockerfile .

Step 14 : RUN cd /tmp &&   curl -O https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/$WILDFLY_VERSION/wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz &&   tar xf wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz &&   mkdir -p $JBOSS_HOME &&   mv /tmp/wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION/* $JBOSS_HOME/ &&   rm -r wildfly-* &&   $JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh admin -p admin -s
 ---> Running in 8f87505a3a73
/bin/sh: curl: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /tmp &&   curl -O https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/$WILDFLY_VERSION/wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz &&   tar xf wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz &&   mkdir -p $JBOSS_HOME &&   mv /tmp/wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION/* $JBOSS_HOME/ &&   rm -r wildfly-* &&   $JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh admin -p admin -s' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Answer (score 1):

Add curl to your alpine image

```
RUN apk update && apk add curl && curl ...
```